# Obtaining coinbase transaction signature

Tags: coinbase-transaction, getblocktemplate

Below is a blocktemplate_blob obtained from calling the getblocktemplate RPC, with reserve size 17.

```
0606e0d8bad7053a15e11686fefb667985fec2a2c89567e2c9dae9e862c76628a174eb3a00662c000000000282d55f01ffc6d45f01e8e4d19ec2870102e8f49622fd8bfd3b0bd8b20ab9f7fc8e33c7f327b0a6a6bda95096d4ab2150813401dd34b8939c64a4237cbd8ea2fad8bf87a5febbd144655e9e697fdd187a2be949021100000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I'm trying to figure out how coinbase transactions are serialized. Based on CNS003 and CNS004, after stripping the block header, transaction version (0x02), unlock time (0x82d55f), num inputs (0x01), transaction type (0xff), block height (0xc6d45f), num outputs (0x01), reward (0xe8e4d19ec28701), and output type (0x02), we are left with

```
e8f49622fd8bfd3b0bd8b20ab9f7fc8e33c7f327b0a6a6bda95096d4ab2150813401dd34b8939c64a4237cbd8ea2fad8bf87a5febbd144655e9e697fdd187a2be949021100000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which I believe consists of the output public key, extra size, and the extra. Removing the extra size and extra leaves us with

```
e8f49622fd8bfd3b0bd8b20ab9f7fc8e33c7f327b0a6a6bda95096d4ab2150813401dd34b8939c64a4237cbd8ea2fad8bf87a5febbd144655e9e697fdd187a2be94902
```

How is this coinbase transaction key generated?

Answer (score 1):

Why would you remove extra ? It's in there.
See cn_deserialize.cpp, to which you can give the hex dump of that tx:

cn_deserialize --input aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa

This will show you the tx key.

Comment: I removed extra to show the portion of the blocktemplate_blob that I wasn't understanding. I'm just lost on the process of generating the last hexstring. Which parameters are used to calculate it?

Comment: Extra is typically composed of a set of chunks. The tx pubkey is a 32 byte chunk. The list of known chunk types and their contents is in tx_extra.h.